# Moving from eigenstate basis of a Hamiltonian back to operator basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

This is maybe a stupid question but one I have been bugged by a long time. 
How to translate back from an eigenstate basis to another operator-basis. 
Let me give an explicit example to show what I am asking.
Consider the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian (dropping vacuum energy)
$$
 H=a^\dagger a
$$
In an eigenstate basis it can be written as
$$
 H=\sum_n n\vert n\rangle\langle n\vert
$$
Now how do I translate terms like 
$$
\vert n\rangle \langle m\vert=f(a,a^\dagger)
$$
in terms of operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$?

Note: I am not asking for ladder operators specifically but for a general construction scheme. This is why this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ form a complete algebra basis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413659/)

Comment: It's perfectly possible but quite messy, see the linked answers.

Comment: This does not answer my question, Maybe I wasn't clear I was more interested in a construction scheme as I plan to use it for all kinds of many body operators

Comment: Right now it looks like you've got a question asking how to translate the eigenstate basis into the ladder operator basis, with something extra tacked on at the end claiming that you're not asking about ladder operators specifically - but that claim isn't supported by the rest of the question. Could you replace the last couple of paragraphs with something that shows you're asking about other operators besides ladder operators?

Comment: As I state in the beginning:
"How to translate back from an eigenstate basis to another operator-basis. Let me give an explicit example."
As you see there even in the second sentence I stated that this is just an example. And I gave that example for concreteness. It seems to me people here are passive aggressive, unwilling to read and just want to create issues while feeling clever for closing every question as a duplicate. That really disgusts me...